# Not able to access sparkcontext inside a scala classs

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am not able to access sc and hc from a scla class EdlUpdate eventhough i have imported the EdlUpdateConf

The error msg i get is "not found value :sc"

```
package com.omega.edl.update.base

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

object EdlUpdateConf {


  val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("EDLUpdateSparkJob")
   .set("spark.network.timeout","1000")

   val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
   val hc = new HiveContext(sc)

}
```

I am trying to access sc and hc in below scala class

```
   package com.omega.edl.update.process

   import com.omega.edl.update.base.{EdlUpdateConf}

   class EdlUpdate extends Serializable {


    def runProject() : Unit = {

     sc.

    }
   }
```

Please help to resolve this syntax error

Comment: I don't think you can refer a local variable from other object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your import statement are not correct.

```
import com.omega.edl.update.base.{EdlUpdateConf}
//Use below imports
import com.omega.edl.update.base.EdlUpdateConf.sc
import com.omega.edl.update.base.EdlUpdateConf.hc
import com.omega.edl.update.base.EdlUpdateConf.conf
//or
import com.omega.edl.update.base.EdlUpdateConf._
```